# Getting data from an RS232 Port using Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, port, device, usbserial

Trying to get the weight from the weighing scale through a port connected to a USB that's connected to my android phone. The data is coming through but I don't know how to convert it properly. This is the code I'm currently using to convert the data:

```
try {
    String data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");

    if (mHandler != null)
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, data).sendToTarget();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is what I'm currently getting:

[image]

The number `14700t` was supposed to show on the `textview`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: you must have specs of the thing u are connected. only it can say which bytes corresponds to the weight and whatever unit it is

Comment: Try print `arg0` as `byte[]` values and analyze them. Probably `"UTF-8"` is wrong encoding.